# WPF - Select ComboBox value by typing when using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatemplate

I have a combobox in wpf which is binded to some property (another object). Because I need to show two properties of that object i used DataTemplate inside combobox. Now when combobox is in focus I can't select some value by typing few starting letters (without DataTemplate it is possible).

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,14,0,0" Name="tipDokumentaCombo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="241" TabIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TipoviDokumenta}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Potvrda.Tip}" SelectedValuePath="Tip" SelectionChanged="tipDokumentaCombo_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tip}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OpisDokumenta}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=")" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set [`TextSearch.TextPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch.textpath.aspx) to the property that should be searched.

**Update**
Because the abvove solution seems not to work for you, try to set the search text manually for the container:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>    
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">        
          <Setter Property="TextSearch.Text" Value="{Binding Tip}" />            
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Can you give me example how would it look? Tnx

Comment: @HLC That is not working as well :( Is there another way to print those two values without DataTemplate?

Comment: @mersadk: This is odd, I cant see what is wrong. I used this quite often and never observed a problem. Are you aware that TextSearch.TextPath is not a Binding but the name of the property? The declaration must be: TextSearch.TextPath="Tip". For the requested alternatives: The most simple is to override ToString() of your BusinessObject and return the string already concatenated. Another try is to use MultiBinding and using only one TextBlock, but I doubt that this helps.

Comment: @HLC I am aware of that and I used it that way but it didn't helped.

Comment: @HLC Finaly found a solution. I added <ComboBox ... IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Tip"> and it worked. I really don't know why that didn't work first time. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Add DisplayMemberPath to the property on which lookup should work on.

Setting DisplayMemberPath worked for me even when itemtemplate is present.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment discussion, the solution that works is to add both `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"` and `TextSearch.TextPath="Tip"` in the `ComboBox` tag.

For example (re-writting the question code sample - removing some not useful to the example code to reduce complexity)

```
<ComboBox Name="tipDokumentaCombo" TabIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TipoviDokumenta}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Potvrda.Tip}" SelectedValuePath="Tip" SelectionChanged="tipDokumentaCombo_SelectionChanged" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Tip">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tip}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OpisDokumenta}" />
                <TextBlock Text=")" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Disclaimer:** I am not the original author. This answer is fabricated from the existing comments. Attribution should be given to [@mersadk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336305/mersadk) who post, most of this answer's details in the comments. I test it and verified that this works in my (similar) environment - issue.